# How to use style in SCSS and HTML in ionic4?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m migrating source code from ionic3 to ionic4.
The usage of text-center in html has changed with this error.

```
[DEPRECATED][CSS] Ionic CSS attributes are deprecated.
Replace:
'<p text-center>'

With:
'<p class="ion-text-center">'
```

How do I write the following code in ionic4?
Please help me.

> Writing for ionic3

**html**

```
<p class="txt_login" text-center (click)="Login()">LOGIN</p>
```

**scss**

```
.txt_login{
    color:white;
    font-size: 10.5rem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use both class names in class attribute

```
<p class="txt_login ion-text-center" (click)="Login()">LOGIN</p>
```

Comment: I tried, but It's not working.<br>The font size is displayed very big.

Comment: @Hyonta, what is the font size of your root element because 10.5 rem is very big.maybe you should use smaller value like 1.5rem